# Replace regular expressions in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I can search for regular expressions in cypher

```
MATCH (n:model) WHERE n.name =~ '.*&.*;.*' RETURN n.name
```

but can I also replace them? I would like to write something like

```
MATCH (n:model) RETURN replace(n.name, ~'&.*;', '_');
```

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087753/neo4j-rename-property-using-regex-of-current-property-value - so, if it is a simple replace a non-regex approach may work.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [replace](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-string.html#functions-replace) function in cypher, but it does not replace regexps, just simple strings.
Maybe a feature request for `replaceRegex` could be done?

An workaround would be to do this programatically, after you return the names (if you use call cypher queries from another application).