# Neo4j query using regex to filter version strings by less than

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a neo4j query for the first time to give me all versions under a certain version number.

To give an example, say I want all versions under "55.555.55" where the version can be anything from "0.0.0" to "999.999.999"

There can be letters after the last number if there's a dash in between, like so, "0.0.0-snapshot".

I am trying to research an approach that allows me to filter these in the query but am having a tough time because they are considered strings and not integers. I want to replace anything that's not a number so I can directly compare the versions. I found the `replace` method in neo4j but it [looks like it can't be used with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816668/replace-regular-expressions-in-cypher).

Is there a way to replace all non numeric values WITHOUT changing the actual node, so I can convert to integers and filter by integer value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `value =~ regexp` to filter for regular expressions.

so in your case `foo.version =~ '\d+\.\d+\.\d+'