# neo4j/Regex: Cypher string REPLACE() replacing string segment only to end or beginning of string

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way in cypher to REPLACE (n.propertyvalue, {search}, {replace}) where there are more conditionals on {search}, like from start of string to delimiter or from delimiter to end of string?

For example, where {search} is 123 and {replace} is 000:

```
CREATE (n:TEST) set n.SWAP_ID="1234_12314123_123";
CREATE (n:TEST) set n.SWAP_ID="123_1312323_1234";
CREATE (n:TEST) set n.SWAP_ID="12434_12314123_123";
CREATE (n:TEST) set n.SWAP_ID="1243_123_1123";
MATCH (n:TEST) set n.WAS_ID=n.SWAP_ID
SET n.SWAP_ID=REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (n.SWAP_ID, '_'+ {search} + '_' , '_'+{replace}+ '_'), '_'+ {search} + '\\$' , '_'+{replace}) , '\\^'+ {search}+'_', {replace}+'_') 
return n.WAS_ID, n.SWAP_ID;
```

I would like:

```
n.WAS_ID                     n.SWAP_ID
"1234_12314123_123"         "1234_12314123_000"
"123_1312323_1234"          "000_1312323_1234"
"12434_12314123_123"        "12434_12314123_000"
"1243_123_1123"             "1243_000_1123"
```

But I get:

```
n.WAS_ID                     n.SWAP_ID
"1234_12314123_123"         "1234_12314123_123"
"123_1312323_1234"          "123_1312323_1234"
"12434_12314123_123"        "12434_12314123_123"
"1243_123_1123"             "1243_000_1123"
```

The end of string and beginning of string are not being recognized. Seems like cypher should be able to do this basic regex stuff, right?

Seems like this came up 5 years ago:
[Neo4j rename property using regex of current property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087753/neo4j-rename-property-using-regex-of-current-property-value)
[Replace regular expressions in cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816668/replace-regular-expressions-in-cypher)

Still no fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
apoc.text.replace(apoc.text.replace(apoc.text.replace(n.WAS_ID, "_" + {search} + "_","_" + {replace} + "_"), "^" + {search} + "_",{replace} + "_"),"_" + {search} + "$","_" + {replace})
```

If you don't have APOC plugin installed, you need to do that first.

Comment: For completeness sake, documentation on this function is [here](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.text/apoc.text.replace/) (for apoc 4.4, current latest).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks NonameCurious!

apoc.text.replace replaces each instance of any regex in the regex substring. 
I haven't tested it with paramters, but it will be something like:

```
MATCH (n:TEST)
SET n.SWAP_ID=apoc.text.replace (apoc.text.replace (REPLACE(n.WAS_ID, '_'+{search}+'_', '_'+{replace}+'_'), "(_"+{search}+"$)" , "_"+{replace}), "(^"+{search}+")" , {replace} + "_")
```

Addendum: does not work with parameters, but does work without parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There is a regular expression that will handle all your edge cases, and you only need to perform a single replacement operation:

```
SET n.SWAP_ID = apoc.text.replace(
  n.SWAP_ID,
  '(^|(?<=_))' + $search + '($|(?=_))',
  $replace)
```

#### Explanation

The [apoc.text.replace](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/misc/text-functions/#text-functions-regex) function simply uses the Java method [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), so any regular expression that conforms to the [documented pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)) is supported.

For your specific use case, this regular expression should work nicely:

```
(^|(?<=_))123($|(?=_))
```

- The `(^|(?<=_))` pattern looks for either the start of the input string or an underscore, but any matching underscore will not be replaced.
- The `($|(?=_))` pattern looks for either the end of the input string or an underscore, but any matching underscore will not be replaced.
- In addition, these patterns allow the same underscore to be considered multiple times (eg., in the string "123_123", as both a trailing underscore AND a leading underscore).

For example, this query:

```
UNWIND [
  "1234_12314123_123",
  "123_1312323_1234",
  "12434_12314123_123",
  "1243_123_1123",
  "123_123_123",
  "123"
] AS x
RETURN x, apoc.text.replace(x, "(^|(?<=_))123($|(?=_))", "000") AS y
```

produces this result:

```
╒════════════════════╤════════════════════╕
│"x"                 │"y"                 │
╞════════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│"1234_12314123_123" │"1234_12314123_000" │
├────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│"123_1312323_1234"  │"000_1312323_1234"  │
├────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│"12434_12314123_123"│"12434_12314123_000"│
├────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│"1243_123_1123"     │"1243_000_1123"     │
├────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│"123_123_123"       │"000_000_000"       │
├────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│"123"               │"000"               │
└────────────────────┴────────────────────┘
```